# Why is it not printing the array?

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

I want to take the contents from a file and print them out in a random order. Right now I am just trying to take the contents from the file and printing it back out. for example right now the file has:

```
0 Abdelmeged Zane
1 Attri Sonal
```

And it prints out the second line not the first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   FILE *file;
   char string[50];
   char array[100];
   int i = 0;
   char *p;

   file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if(file == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }

   printf("\nOriginal Array: \n");
   while(fgets(string, 100, file)!= NULL) {
       printf(string);
       p = &array[i];
       strcpy(p, string);
       i++;
   }

   i = 0;
   printf("\nShuffled Array: \n");
   while(i < 20){
       printf("%c", array[i]);
       i++;
   }

   fclose(file);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: **Note:** you **cannot** return `-1` from `main()`. Other functions -- yes, `main` -- **no**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you declare `char array[100];` and then essentially **overwrite** the string you store in it with `strcpy(p, string);` with each iteration of your `while` loop. There is no need to use a pointer `p` in this case. What you need to do is allocate **multiple** pointers to hold **multiple** strings. The normal way is to allocate some number of pointers (10 below -- see MAXLINES), and then allocate space for each string as you use each pointer. The following is a quick example (note there are many different ways to do this). Also, since you are allocating memory, you are responsible for freeing it as well (also shown below). Drop a comment if you have questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINES 10

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *file;
    char string[50];
    char **array = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input. Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    array = calloc (MAXLINES, sizeof (*array));    /* MAXLINES char pointers */
    if (!array) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: calloc pointer allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }


    printf("\nOriginal Array: \n");
    while(fgets(string, 100, file)!= NULL) {
        printf("  %s", string);
        array[i] = strdup (string); /* strdup allocates space for string    */
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);                    /* close it here, you are done with it */

    i = 0;                           /* print array stored in memory        */
    printf("\nShuffled Array: \n");
    while (array[i])
    {
        printf("  %s", array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (array[i])                /* free memory dynamically allocated:   */
    {
        free (array[i]);            /* free array/string memory             */
        i++;
    }
    if (array) free (array);        /* free pointer allocation              */

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** you should also save the number of strings read after your loop with `fgets` (e.g. `int numlines = i;`). Do this **before** you reset `i = 0;`. That way you have a convenient reference to the number of strings to use in your shuffle. (you can also always use the `while (array[i])` loop to count them again, but why?

**input file:**

```
$ cat dat/abde.txt
0 Abdelmeged Zane
1 Attri Sonal
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/shufs dat/abde.txt

Original Array:
  0 Abdelmeged Zane
  1 Attri Sonal

Shuffled Array:
  0 Abdelmeged Zane
  1 Attri Sonal
```

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the string you read into the second char array, offsetting the start point by one each time. So at the end, assuming you don't have a buffer overflow, then your `array` will hold the first character of each line up to the last, which it will hold in its entirety.

Depending where you are in your study, either create a static array of arrays of chars to hold each line, or an array of pointers and `malloc` the copy you save.